# Ansible variable assignment

Tags: variables, ansible, increment, roles

I want to run a role 10 times in a playbook and only on the 5th run of that role, I want it to run the second shell cmd from within that role. How can I address that? 
Playbook:

```
- name: bla bla
  hosts: ALL
  remote_user: root
  vars:
     some_variable: 0
  roles:
    - role: nonreg
  whentorun:
    - post
```

The actual role is this:

```
- name: basic
  shell: /scripts/nonReg/expoNonRegTest.sh {{ item }}
  {{ some variable }} ++ ???
  with_items: "{{ whentorun }}"
- name: on 5th run
  shell: /scripts/nonReg/expoNonRegTest.sh diff
  when: {{ some variable }} == 5 ????
```

How can I do that?
How can I declare a variable and assign a value to it (during the run o a role/playbook)? What is the syntax ? In the ansible documentation, at variables, there isn't a simple example of how can you assign a value to a variable (not with register :P)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `set_fact` module to increment your variable:

```
- set_fact: some_variable={{ some_variable | int + 1 }}
```

Your condition for running the extra task then should look like this:

```
  when: some_variable | int == 5
```

Make sure you always cast the value to an int with `| int` or it will be handled as a string.